# Sql Server Updating column by generating random number

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-update

I try to update my column with random number in `Sql Server 2008 R2`.

For example `myTable` is like below:

```
id  password
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   NULL
4   NULL
5   NULL
5   NULL
5   NULL
```

When I update `password` by generating 5 digit random number, table be like:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET password =   CONVERT(numeric(5,0),RAND(convert(varbinary,newid()))*89999)+10000

id  password
1   87781
2   15395
3   62154
4   74194
4   49599
5   54090
5   47287
5   63193
```

And, my problem is generating `password` for each `id`. 
Could help me about query which is giving that result:

```
id  password
1   87781
2   15395
3   62154
4   74194
4   74194
5   54090
5   54090
5   54090
```

Comment: Why not to do second update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first update you can do another one like:

```
;with cte as(select *, min(password) over(partition by id) as pnew from myTable)
update cte set password = pnew
```